# Problemas com atribuição em pilha no Python

Tags: python

Estou tendo um problema com um código de pilha, está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

```
line 9 in empilhar_pilha: novo_numero.proximo = pilha.topo
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'proximo'
line 18, in desempilhar_pilha: pilha.topo = pilha.topo.proximo
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'proximo'
```

Sem falar que a **opção 4 Listar pilha não aparece nada**.

```
class Pilha:
    topo = None

class Elemento:
    numero: float
    proximo = None

def empilhar_pilha(pilha, novo_numero):
    novo_numero.proximo = pilha.topo
    pilha.topo = novo_numero
    print(f"Elemento {novo_numero.numero} foi inserido no topo da pilha")

def desempilhar_pilha(pilha):
    if tamanho_pilha(pilha) == 0:
        print("A pilha está vazia")
    else:
        elemento_excluido = pilha.topo
        pilha.topo = pilha.topo.proximo
        exclusao_feita = elemento_excluido.numero
        del elemento_excluido
        print(f"Elemento ({exclusao_feita}) foi excluido do topo da pilha")

def tamanho_pilha(pilha):
    if (pilha_vazia(pilha) == True):
        return 0
    else:
        contador_pilha = 0
        numero_pilha = pilha.topo
        while numero_pilha != None:
            contador_pilha += 1
            numero_pilha = numero_pilha.proximo
        return contador_pilha

def pilha_vazia(pilha):
    situacao_pilha = (pilha.topo == None)
    return situacao_pilha

def listar_pilha(pilha):
    if pilha_vazia(pilha) == 0:
        print("A pilha esta vazia\n")
    else:
        ver_numero = pilha.topo
        while ver_numero != None:
            print(ver_numero.numero, end= "--> Topo\n" if ver_numero == pilha.topo else print())
            ver_numero = ver_numero.proximo

pilha_pilhosa = Pilha()
opcao = 1
while opcao != 5:
    print ("1 - Empilhar")
    print ("2 - Desempilhar")
    print ("3 - Informar tamanho da pilha")
    print ("4 - Listar pilha")
    print ("5 - Sair")
    opcao = int(input("Informe a opcao: "))
    if opcao == 1:
       numero_informado = float(input("Digite um número: "))
       empilhar_pilha(pilha_pilhosa, numero_informado)
    elif opcao == 2:
       desempilhar_pilha(pilha_pilhosa)
    elif opcao == 3:
       print(f"Tamanho da pilha é de {tamanho_pilha(pilha_pilhosa)} elementos\n")
    elif opcao == 4:
       listar_pilha(pilha_pilhosa)
    elif opcao == 5:
        print("Saindo...\n")
    else:
        print("Opcao invalida, digite uma opcao valida no menu\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está declarando os atributos da classe `Elemento` de forma estática, isso faz com que cada `Elemento` use o mesmo espaço de memória para armazenar os atributos `proximo` e `numero`, impossibilitando a criação da estrutura dinâmica de sua pilha.

A classe `Pilha` também está declarando o atributo de classe `topo` de forma estática, isso impossibilita que você tenha mais de uma instância de `Pilha`.

Segue seu código com algumas correções a fim de torná-lo mais compacto e funcional:

```
class Pilha:
    def __init__(self):
        self.topo = None

class Elemento:
    def __init__(self, n, p ):
        self.numero = n
        self.proximo = p

def empilhar_pilha(pilha, novo_numero):
    novo_elemento = Elemento( novo_numero, pilha.topo )
    pilha.topo = novo_elemento
    print("Elemento {} foi inserido no topo da pilha".format(novo_elemento.numero) )

def desempilhar_pilha(pilha):
    if pilha.topo == None:
        print("A pilha está vazia\n")
        return
    elemento_excluido = pilha.topo
    pilha.topo = pilha.topo.proximo
    exclusao_feita = elemento_excluido.numero
    del elemento_excluido
    print("Elemento ({}) foi excluido do topo da pilha".format(exclusao_feita) )

def tamanho_pilha(pilha):
    if (pilha.topo == None ):
        return 0
    contador_pilha = 0
    numero_pilha = pilha.topo
    while numero_pilha != None:
        contador_pilha += 1
        numero_pilha = numero_pilha.proximo
    return contador_pilha

def listar_pilha(pilha):
    if pilha.topo == None:
        print("A pilha esta vazia\n")
        return
    ver_numero = pilha.topo
    while ver_numero != None:
        print(ver_numero.numero);
        ver_numero = ver_numero.proximo


pilha_pilhosa = Pilha()

while True:

    print ("1 - Empilhar")
    print ("2 - Desempilhar")
    print ("3 - Informar tamanho da pilha")
    print ("4 - Listar pilha")
    print ("5 - Sair")

    opcao = int(input("Informe a opcao: "))

    if opcao == 1:
       numero_informado = float(input("Digite um número: "))
       empilhar_pilha(pilha_pilhosa, numero_informado)
    elif opcao == 2:
       desempilhar_pilha(pilha_pilhosa)
    elif opcao == 3:
       print("Tamanho da pilha eh de {} elementos\n".format(tamanho_pilha(pilha_pilhosa)))
    elif opcao == 4:
       listar_pilha(pilha_pilhosa)
    elif opcao == 5:
        print("Saindo...\n")
        break;
    else:
        print("Opcao invalida, digite uma opcao valida no menu\n")
```

Você pode tornar toda as suas funções em membros da classe `Pilha`, veja só:

```
class Elemento:
    def __init__(self, n, p ):
        self.numero = n
        self.proximo = p

class Pilha:
    def __init__(self):
        self.topo = None

    def empilhar(self, novo_numero):
        novo_elemento = Elemento( novo_numero, self.topo )
        self.topo = novo_elemento
        print("Elemento {} foi inserido no topo da pilha".format(novo_elemento.numero) )

    def desempilhar(self):
        if self.topo == None:
            print("A pilha está vazia\n")
            return
        elemento_excluido = self.topo
        self.topo = self.topo.proximo
        exclusao_feita = elemento_excluido.numero
        del elemento_excluido
        print("Elemento ({}) foi excluido do topo da pilha".format(exclusao_feita) )

    def tamanho(self):
        if (self.topo == None ):
            return 0
        contador_pilha = 0
        numero_pilha = self.topo
        while numero_pilha != None:
            contador_pilha += 1
            numero_pilha = numero_pilha.proximo
        return contador_pilha

    def listar(self):
        if self.topo == None:
            print("A pilha esta vazia\n")
            return
        ver_numero = self.topo
        while ver_numero != None:
            print(ver_numero.numero);
            ver_numero = ver_numero.proximo


pilha_pilhosa = Pilha()

while True:

    print ("1 - Empilhar")
    print ("2 - Desempilhar")
    print ("3 - Informar tamanho da pilha")
    print ("4 - Listar pilha")
    print ("5 - Sair")

    opcao = int(input("Informe a opcao: "))

    if opcao == 1:
       numero_informado = float(input("Digite um número: "))
       pilha_pilhosa.empilhar(numero_informado)
    elif opcao == 2:
       pilha_pilhosa.desempilhar()
    elif opcao == 3:
       print("Tamanho da pilha eh de {} elementos\n".format(pilha_pilhosa.tamanho()))
    elif opcao == 4:
       pilha_pilhosa.listar()
    elif opcao == 5:
        print("Saindo...\n")
        break;
    else:
        print("Opcao invalida, digite uma opcao valida no menu\n")
```

Comment: Esse tipo de código serve para fila?

Comment: ```class Elemento:
    def __init__(self, n, p ):
        self.numero = n
        self.proximo = p``` me explica essa parte

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado @Lacobus.

Comment: @AlexF.: É um construtor: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construtor#Python

Comment: Certo então, obrigado de novo.